# Не получается свернуть меню в бутерброд

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Приветствую. У меня бутстраповское меню, хочу при уменьшении экрана сворачивать его в бутерброд. Не могу понять почему не работает.. Вот [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/t2vgf5pb/).
В описании бутстрапа есть такая строчка:

> Внимание! Для работы динамического Navbar'а необходим collapse плагин и файл динамического Bootstrap CSS.

как понимаю `bootstrap-collapse.js` уже должен быть включен в сборку, а что такое динамический Bootstrap CSS? У меня еще что-то еще не подключено?

```js
< link href = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel = "stylesheet" >
  < script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" > < /script>
<script src="http:/ / netdna.bootstrapcdn.com / bootstrap / 3.1.1 / js / bootstrap.min.js "></script>
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar используется для показа/скрытия контента -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Поместите сюда все что вы хотите скрыть на дисплеях с шириной менее 940px -->
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="about.html"><span>О заводе</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="product.html"><span>Продукция</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="services.html"><span>Услуги</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="news.html"><span>Новости</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Контакты</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="requisites.html"><span>Реквизиты</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам просто не повезло с примером. В коде было буквально всё не так (или не от той версии TWBS?).

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Поместите сюда все что вы хотите скрыть на дисплеях с шириной менее 940px -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="about.html"><span>О заводе</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="product.html"><span>Продукция</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="services.html"><span>Услуги</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="news.html"><span>Новости</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Контакты</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="requisites.html"><span>Реквизиты</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2vgf5pb/1/

Рекомендую разобрать примеры с официального сайта и обратить внимание на то, как работает `collapse` через `a href`.

P.S. `navbar` должен иметь добавочный класс либо `navbar-default`, либо `navbar-inverse`, как у меня в примере. Иначе не видать Вам бутера =)